# Go variadic function argument passing

Tags: go

I am trying to understand, What is difference between 1st and 2nd passing argument in function. In both case methods are functional and compiles.

1)

```
generateReport(capacities...)

func generateReport(capacities ...float64) {
    for i, cap := range capacities {
        fmt.Printf("Plant %d capacity %.0f\n", i, cap)
    }
}
```

2)

```
generateReport(plantCapacities)

func generateReport(capacities []float64) {
    for i, cap := range capacities {
        fmt.Printf("Plant %d capacity %.0f\n", i, cap)
    }
}
```

**Have found few good samples**

1) [GolangBot - Variadic Function](https://golangbot.com/variadic-functions/)

2) [Golang.org - Passing arguments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) as @Himanshu mentioned.

Comment: The question displays absense of even a minimal research as skimming through any inctoructory material on Go should have covered it.

Comment: "inctoructory" is't russian word?

Comment: It should have been introductory. I'm pretty sure that were Putin's hackers controlling my fat fingers, as they usually do.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Golang language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

> If f is variadic with a final parameter p of type ...T, then within f
>   the type of p is equivalent to type []T. If f is invoked with no
>   actual arguments for p, the value passed to p is nil. Otherwise, the
>   value passed is a new slice of type []T with a new underlying array
>   whose successive elements are the actual arguments, which all must be
>   assignable to T. The length and capacity of the slice is therefore the
>   number of arguments bound to p and may differ for each call site.

`variadic` functions are used to handle multiple trailing arguments. It can be used to pass slice arguments.

```
func main(){
  capacities := []float64{1, 2, 3, 4}
  generateReport(capacities...)
}

func generateReport(capacities ...float64) {
    for i, cap := range capacities {
        fmt.Printf("Plant %d capacity %.0f\n", i, cap)
    }
}
```

Variadic functions can also be called in usual way with individual arguments. It works like spread operator in java script which can take multiple arguments. For eg:-

```
func main(){
  generateReport(1,2,3,4)
}

func generateReport(capacities ...float64) {
    for i, cap := range capacities {
        fmt.Printf("Plant %d capacity %.0f\n", i, cap)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, figure it out -> https://golangbot.com/variadic-functions already thx.