# how to pass dynamic argument in function

Tags: go

## What I am doing

```
 func foo(a string) {}

 func bar(b, c string)

 type fn func(string)

 m: = map[string] fn {
     "a": "foo",
     "b": "bar"
 }
```

## What is output

when I call function like this

```
  m["a"]("Hello")
  m["b"]("Hello", "World")
```

I got an error because `type fn func(string)` here fn have single parameter but I pass double parameter in `m["b"]("Hello", "World")`

> Error : [ cannot use (type func(string, string)) as type fn in map
>   value ]

## What I am looking for

I want to make dynamic `type fn func(string)` so that I can pass number of parameter so that I can call like this

```
  m["a"]("Hello")
  m["b"]("Hello", "World")
```

Comment: What you want to do is _impossible_ in Go: You have to redesign.

Comment: @Volker Can you please help me in that how to design?

Comment: All you can do is use variadic function to take any number of arguments.@Volker is correct

Comment: Thank you @Himanshu I am trying this also

Comment: You must come up with a single function type which allows all the use cases. Variadic functions are one solution. Functions taking an interface argument might be an other.

Comment: I am trying to do this with `interface{}` this is right approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve using interface

```
m: = map[string]interface{} {
     "a": "foo",
     "b": "bar"
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a variadic function which will take any number of arguments as parameters on passing it to function.

```
 func foo(nums ...string) {}

 m:= map[string]fn{
     "a": "foo",
     "b": "bar"
 }
```

For more on variadic functions check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849493/go-variadic-function-argument-passing/48849643#48849643)

Comment: No I can't do this because then i need to check inside foo function that how many arguments are coming

Comment: you can do that by checking on struct rather than on every function