# Passing a fixed length array to a function

Tags: go

I want to write a function that can accept arrays of fixed length, but different arrays have different lengths.

I know that i can pass the slice with arr[:] (the function will accept []T), but is there another way, maybe more efficient?

I'm using a struct that i'd like to mantain with fixed length arrays (for documentation purposes), so using slices everywhere at declaration time is not optimal for my purpose.

Comment: Just use slice, array is not suitable to be passed as param, it will make a copy, waste space & time, also there are two copy of undering data.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849493/go-variadic-function-argument-passing/48849643#48849643 might be of help.

Comment: Slicing an array is not inefficient at all. See https://blog.golang.org/slices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is no way to pass different size arrays, because the length of an array is part of the type.

For example `[3]int` is a different type then `[2]int`.

At all in Go it is not recommended to use arrays you should use slices (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#arrays).

Comment: Another reason not to use array is, when pass array as param, it will make a copy, anyway this won't work.